# Probability of joint distribution

Tags: statistics

We were given some exercises to do to prepare for an upcoming quiz and there's one question that I'm struggling on.

If $X ∼ N (μ = 10, σ^2 = 4)$ and $Y ∼ N (μ = 8, σ^2 = 16)$.  Assume that
X and Y are independent.
Find $P(X\ge 11|Y\le7)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your random variable to a standard random variable and then use a standard normal table. You don't integrate normal random variable.

If X is a random variable from a normal distribution with mean μ and standard deviation σ, its Z-score may be calculated from X by subtracting μ and dividing by σ.

In your case, $P(X>11)=1-P(X<11)=1-P(\frac{X-μ}{σ})<\frac{11-10}{2})=1-P(Z<\frac{1}{2})$ where $Z$ is $N(0,1)$.

Now use a standard normal table, also called the unit normal table or Z table, which gives the values of the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal random variable. Go to Wikipedia for the table and examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just figured it out right before you commented.

Answer (score 3):

Since they're independent, $P(X\geq 11|Y \leq 7) = P(X\geq 11)$.

Comment: How do I find P(X>11)? I haven't got any function to integrate.

Comment: any further explanation please?

Comment: @samir91 Do you have _any_ understanding of what $X ∼ N (μ = 10, σ^2 = 4)$ means?

Comment: nvm i got it. Thanks for the help @NicNic8.

Comment: Also @Dilip if you're not gonna be helpful, I suggest that you don't say anything at all.

Comment: @samir91 glad you got it.  :)